# Prestashop 1.7 add new variables into email total_shipping_tax_excl

Tags: email, overriding, prestashop-1.7

I need delivery cost excluded tax in email confirmation. I made changes:

1. in email translation order_conf I put {total_shipping_tax_excl}
2. I made override in /override/classes/order/OrderHistory.php

   ```
   class OrderHistory extends OrderHistoryCore
   {   
       public function sendEmail($order, $template_vars = false)
       {
           $data = array(
                   '{total_shipping_tax_excl}' => Tools::displayPrice($order->total_shipping_tax_excl, $this->context->currency, false)
               );
           //die (print_r($data,true));    
           if ($template_vars) {
                   $data = array_merge($data, $template_vars);
               }

           return parent::sendEmail($order, $data);
       }
   }
   ```

Override works - if I make die (print_r($data,true)); I can see that proper value is in total_shipping_tax_excl key. Email translation works - I see new string. But when email is sent then I have just {total_shipping_tax_excl} string.

What am I missing?

Comment: I made change directly in /classes/order/OrderHistory.php but no results. It seems that something remembers what string can be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enthu was right. First problem was that confirmation email is generated in classes/PaymentModule.php not in  /classes/order/OrderHistory.php . 
Solution is to override original file or wait. I made pull request: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/11396 and chage was accepted so {total_shipping_tax_excl} and {total_shipping_tax_incl} will be in 1.7.6

Answer (score 1):

I was also editing the email template for Order Confirmation. You need to edit PaymentModule.php for it to work. You can also set the email subject directly from this file.

Around line 756

```
// Send an e-mail to customer (one order = one email)
if ($id_order_state != Configuration::get('PS_OS_ERROR') && $id_order_state != Configuration::get('PS_OS_CANCELED') && $this->context->customer->id) {
    $invoice = new Address((int)$order->id_address_invoice);
    $delivery = new Address((int)$order->id_address_delivery);
```